# MS Access stopped working after creating E-Mail via EMailDatabaseObject (Macro)

Tags: ms-access, outlook

We are using `EMailDatabaseObject` in a macro to send reports via e-mail (as pdf). After closing Outlook's message dialog by either sending the e-mail or simply closing the window it takes about 2 minutes (on my machine) before "*MS Access has stopped working*".

I get the following problem details:

```
Problem signature:
    Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
    Application Name:   MSACCESS.EXE
    Application Version:    16.0.9330.2087
    Application Timestamp:  5b049173
    Fault Module Name:  olmapi32.dll
    Fault Module Version:   16.0.9330.2087
    Fault Module Timestamp: 5b04968a
    Exception Code: c0000005
    Exception Offset:   0005015f
    OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.49
    Locale ID:  1031
```

What I've tried so far (with no luck):

- Check for updates (latest versions of "everything" installed)
- Try on different machines (Win 8, 10)
- Decompile / Compact & Repair / Compile
- Remove binary data from form
- Create an new form
- Use E-Mail option in Ribbon
- "Quick Repair" Office 365

Does anybody encouter similar issues or is there anything else I should try?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new Outlook profile?

Comment: @Rene No, I haven't. Do you also suggest to remove the existing profile or just create a second one?

Comment: @Rene UPDATE: Created a new profile. Unfortunately with no effect.

Comment: Another update: I'm not able to reproduce the problem anymore. Haven't done anything that could have fixed it. I hate Windows :/